# Memory error: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, memory, stl, stack-trace, push-back

I'm trying to implement a `radix sort`, and this code produce a memory failure:

```
(free(): invalid next size (fast))
```

The code is the following:

```
unsigned int * radix(unsigned int *x,int n, int g,bool verbose)
{
    int elem_size = sizeof(unsigned int)*8;
    int mask = ((1<<g)-1);    
    float num_rounds= ((float)elem_size/(float)g);
    int B = 1 << g; // 2^g BTW

    vector<unsigned int> buckets[B];

    // begin radix sort
    for( unsigned int round=0 ; round<num_rounds ; ++round)
      {

        // count
        for(int elem=0 ; elem<n ; ++elem)
        {
            // calculate the bucket number:
            unsigned int const bucket_num = ( x[elem] >> g*round) & mask;
    --->        buckets[bucket_num].push_back(x[elem]);
        }
        // more stuff
    }
    return x;
}
```

`GDB` states that the error is inside push_back, but `elem` is always smaller than `n` (where `n` is the size of `x[]`). So, I thought that it could only be on `bucket_num`. However, just before it crashes `GDB` gives me their values:

> ```
> Breakpoint 1, radix (x=0x604010, n=50, g=4, verbose=true)
>     at radix.mpi.seq.cpp:38
> 38                buckets[bucket_num].push_back(x[elem]);
> 2: B = 16
> 1: bucket_num = 2
> ```

any ideas?

Comment: is `//more stuff` actual code?  You need to include all of the code.  Just because the crash was on a line, does not mean that's where the problem is.

Comment: //more stuff was code, but I comment and the error remain

Comment: I have no idea why, but I changed the memory allocator from 'new unsigned int(n)' to 'malloc((n*sizeof(unsigned int))' and it works just fine.

Any reasonable explanation?

Comment: @RSF Neither line appears in your original question. It's hard to diagnose problems in code you haven't shown us. (Aside: I don't think `new unsigned int(n)` means what you think it does.)

Comment: @AlanStokes ya! you are right! haste is the enemy of perfection...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/c-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment, it's clear that: accessing `unsigned int *x` is the reason for the invalid write error you get when you access it in your `radix` function.

`unsigned int *x = new unsigned int(n);` allocates a *single* unsigned int and assigns the value `n` to it. You really wanted an array of unsigned ints:
`unsigned int *x = new unsigned int[n];`

In general, running through [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) helps find memory leaks and where exactly the problem lies. Because, often the error message you get hardly happens at a line where it *appears* to happen.