# Simple C++ program crashes

Tags: c++

For some reason, the following program crashes before "i got here" is printed. When I comment out the try-catch part, the program runs and exits normally.

```
#include <iostream>

int error_function () {

    throw 5;

    return 0;
}


int main () {

    double* b = new double[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        b[i] = i;
    }

    double* c = new double(*b);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        c[i] = i+1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        std::cout << b[i] << " " << c[i] << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        error_function();
    }
    catch (int t) {
        std::cout << "catched an int: " << t << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "i got here" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the entire output I get when the program crashes:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
catched an int: 5
*** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001f22070 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x77806)[0x7f2b273a0806]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x7f2b273a70d3]
./main[0x400d92]
(a bunch of stuff)
Aborted
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/c-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast). Or at least the same error with an answer~

Comment: I'm confused at why you're using arrays like that. Even without the better containers, why not just `double b[6]; double c[6];` You can also combine the filling loops (and even printing) into just one, or use `std::iota` to fill them if you have C++11.

Comment: Hi chris, I wrote the program that way because i'm trying to understand what double c* = new double(b*) does exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's crashing because you've only allocated one double when you allocate c and then proceed to overrun the bounds by accessing elements after the first. It looks as if in this case after the exception has been handled there is some cleanup and the glibc has detected corrupt memory.

The problem lines are these:

```
double* c = new double(*b);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        c[i] = i+1;
}
```

It allocates a new double that copies the value of *b (or b[0] if you like) because b is just a pointer so dereferencing it does not invoke the copy constructor that copies an array.

You would be better off using a std::vector as it would automatically take care of any memory allocation and deallocation for you as well as being exception safe. In the case your `error_function` threw an exception that you did not handle it would still clean up correctly, whereas your `new`'d memory does not as it stands.

Technically it's undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

Comment: To be more accurate, even the principle of using `new` is fail.

Comment: @DeadMG: Indeed, I've highlight a couple of reasons not to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks tinman, that clarifies it. I just wrote this program to play with some features of the language. In practice I would never allocate arrays in this manner and indeed use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
double* c = new double(*b);
```

This is allocating space for one double and giving it an initial value of `b[0]`. Later on you are assigning to `c[1]`, etc. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [timans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583044/tinman) answer.

Your program is doing a heap overrun.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    c[i] = i+1;
}
```

double c[0] has an address of new double and value of b[0].but c[1],c[2],.... they may overwrite any other system information related to the program and then behavior becomes uncertain.

Change this line and the program should work fine

```
double* c = new double[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    c[i] = b[i]+1;
}
```

and don't forget to call delete[] before returning from main.

Comment: I think the OP meant to copy the value of the elements of b to the newly allocated elements of c, so you'd need to include something to copy those elements after allocating c to have it the same functionality.

Comment: Better but I just re-read the code after his allocation and now I'm not sure whether he meant to copy it since he overwrites it immediately. So either this version or your previous version are probably both suitable.