# g_strsplit giving me an error ( free(): invalid next size)

Tags: c, glib

I am making use of glib 2.0 API. I am reading a CSV file, and making use of the g_strsplit function to get the data between the commas. The following is my code:

```
gchar* record = get_record_from_file();
printf("Record: %s\n", record); <--- WORKS CORRECTLY
gchar** data = g_strsplit(record, ",", 6); <-- ERROR HERE
free(record);
```

When I use the split method, I get an error. Here is my output.

> Record: 2,0.4,2,0,1,10,
>
> *** glibc detected *** /path/to/my/project: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001c06a00 ***

I tried googling the error. Apparently, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/c-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast) question and answer, the error has to do with memory:

> It means that you have a memory error. You may be trying to free a
>   pointer that wasn't allocated by malloc (or delete an object that
>   wasn't created by new) or you may be trying to free/delete such an
>   object more than once. You may be overflowing a buffer or otherwise
>   writing to memory to which you shouldn't be writing, causing heap
>   corruption.

Is the g_strsplit being called correctly? Why am I getting this error?

[Doc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strsplit):

> string :a string to split.
>
> delimiter : a string which specifies the places at which to split the
>   string. The delimiter is not included in any of the resulting strings,
>   unless max_tokens is reached.
>
> max_tokens :the maximum number of pieces to split string into. If this
>   is less than 1, the string is split completely.
>
> Returns :a newly-allocated NULL-terminated array of strings. Use
>   g_strfreev() to free it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. I got the that error because my buffer's size was too small to hold the data. I increased it, and the error is gone.

Comment: Good to hear. There was nothing else obvious in the code you posted. Using a tool like valgrind can help spot memory issues like this in the future

Comment: Thanks @iain for all your help. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should call `g_strsplit` like so

```
gchar **data = g_strsplit (result, ",", 6);
```

The reason is because `g_strsplit` is expecting a NULL terminated string for `delimiter` and `&delimiter` gives the memory address of a single character with no NULL character afterwards so it writes over some memory

Comment: Although it was a mistake and thank you for pointing it out, the error is still there =S

Comment: In that case, how was your `record` allocated? Using malloc or g_malloc? Or is it actually a const string that shouldn't be freed?

Comment: @iain gchar *buff = malloc(sizeof(gchar) * 1024);