# Error free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08912058

Tags: c++

As part of an exercise, I am modifying this class that represents a different way of creating arrays:

```
template<class T>
class Array 
{
public:

Array(int size, T defaultvalue) : _size(size) 
    {
    _arr = new T[_size] ;
    _def = defaultvalue;
    }


Array(const Array& other) : _size(other._size) 
    {
    _arr = new T[other._size] ;
    // Copy elements
    for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++) 
        {
            _arr[i] = other._arr[i] ;
            }
    }

~Array() 
    {
        delete[] _arr ;
    }


Array& operator=(const Array& other) 
    {
    if (&other==this) return *this ;
        if (_size != other._size) 
        {
            resize(other._size) ;
            }
        for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++) 
        {
            _arr[i] = other._arr[i] ;
            }
        return *this ;
    }

T& operator[](int index) 
    {           
        if (index>_size)
        {
        int prevsize = _size;
        resize(index);
        for (int i = prevsize+1; i<=index; i++)
            {
            _arr[i] = _def;
            }
        }
        return _arr[index] ;
    }

const T& operator[](int index) const 
    {
        if (index>_size)
        {
        int prevsize = _size;
        resize(index);
        for (int i = prevsize+1; i<=index; i++)
            {
            _arr[i] = _def;
            }
        }
        return _arr[index] ;
    }

int size() const { return _size;}

T defval() const { return _def;}

void resize(int newSize) 
    {
        // Allocate new array
        T* newArr = new T[newSize] ;
    // Copy elements
    for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++) 
        {
            newArr[i] = _arr[i] ;
            }
    // Delete old array and install new one
        delete[] _arr ;
        _size = newSize ;
        _arr = newArr ;
    }


private:
int _size ;
T* _arr ;
T _def;
} ;
```

Now this works fine with arrays of ints, but it gives me

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08912058 ***
```

When I do, for instance:

```
const char* one = new char[3];
one = "abc";
Array<const char*> b(2, one);
```

This should create an array of length 2, and any time I acces any element with index > 2, it should return the string "abc". When I access such an element, the array returns what it's supposed to, but I get the aforementioned error. The error is followed by a backtrace.

Comment: Sorry. I edited in more of the error.

Comment: Use copy-swap. It's a lot safer. You're also allocating memory for `one` and then leaking it right after.

Comment: "I do, for instance..": you are ignoring the returned new char array and replacing it with a pointer to the constant string "abc". Are you sure you wouldn't want to use `strcpy` instead? (Which would need an additional byte in your new line.)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `Array< char >`? Because you are creating array of pointers to `char`, not array of `char`. Also, judging by the way you assign to `char *`, I think, you need better understanding of what happens there.

Comment: Yes, I want an array of pointers to chars. I'm trying to learn C++ and the pointers keep confusing me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your resize function resizes to the size you give it (i.e. `index`), but then you set the array up to (and including) `index`. That's an invalid index - your array goes from `0` to `index-1`.

I'm talking about those lines:

```
resize(index);
for (int i = prevsize+1; i<=index; i++)
```

So you need to call `resize` with `index+1` to fix this problem.

Also:

```
const char* one = new char[3];
one = "abc";
```

This simply leaks memory (you allocate a new buffer and then immediately set `one` to `"abc"` which is a different pointer).

Answer (score 2):

```
const char* one = new char[3];
one = "abc";
```

The above assignment doesn't do a deep copy to the memory location you acquired. `one` is pointing to the string literal causing memory leak.

You are not responsible for deleting string literals. They have static storage duration and the operating system reclaims it's memory once the program quits.

Comment: I understand what I do wrong in the first case, but not in the second. Why is that the same problem?

Comment: @RobVerheyen Sorry. I didn't notice you are assigning to `_def`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't do this:

```
const char* one = new char[3];
one = "abc";
```

You need to use `new` if you want to something like this:

```
char* one = new char[4];
one[0] = 'a';
one[1] = 'b';
one[2] = 'c';
one[3] = 0; // null terminator
```

But, that's overkill when you just want it to point to a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) (like "abc"). Just do this:

```
const char* one = "abc";
```

Also, you'll find that C++ is *much* easier if you use `std::string` instead of `char*`.