# Why free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, memory, struct, g++, free

Please, see the c-code and help me. Why i have "free(): invalid next size (fast)" ? I try valgrind, but don't understand, there are too much "invalid write/read ....", but if I comment free_array(all) a have right answers. It's just a part of all code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pair {
    uint32_t num;
    uint32_t effect;
};

struct array {
    size_t size;
    struct pair data[];
};

size_t sizeof_array(size_t size)
{
    return sizeof(struct array) + (size * sizeof(uint32_t));
}

struct pair *create_pair(uint32_t i, uint32_t eff)
{
    struct pair *ret = calloc(2, sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (! ret)
        abort();
    ret->num = i;
    ret->effect = eff;
    return ret;
}

struct array *create_array(size_t size)
{
    struct array *ret = calloc(1, sizeof_array(size));
    if (! ret) 
        abort();
    ret->size = size;
    return ret;
}

void free_array(struct array *array)
{
//    size_t i;
//    for (i = 0; i < array->size; ++i) {
//        free(&array->data[i]);
//    }
    free(array);
}

int main()
    {
    int eff;
    size_t n;
    scanf("%zu", &n);
    struct array *all = create_array(n);
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &eff);
        all->data[i] = *create_pair(i, eff);
    }

    free_array(all);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `calloc(2, sizeof(uint32_t));` -> `calloc(1, sizeof *ret)` to be safe. You can never know where (and how much) alignment there is.

Comment: If you're allocating memory for a structure, use that structure as base for the allocation (I'm talking about your `create_pair` function where you allocate to `uint32_t` instead of one `struct pair`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, don't use the size of each member of a structure as base when allocating memory, use the actual structure. This is the cause of your problem as your function `sizeof_array` returns a size approximately half the size you need.

Instead it should look something like

```
size_t sizeof_array(size_t size)
{
    return sizeof(struct array) + (size * sizeof(struct pair));
    /* Notice the use of the structure instead   ^^^^^^^^^^^ */
}
```

Because `sizeof_array` returns a too small size, you allocate too little memory and write beyonds the bound of your allocated memory, and then end up with *undefined behavior*.

---

You also have memory leaks, as you allocate memory for each `struct pair` in the array. When you allocate the `array` structure you already allocate memory for each `pair`, there's no need to allocate each one by one, especially since you just discard the pointer and therefore have a memory leak.

And when freeing, just free the `array` structure, as that's all you (should) allocate.

Comment: Thank's, you a right! Now I've not "free():invalid next size" and passed first 9 tests) And now I have unknown RE error in 10 test, but I can't see test input(

Comment: In the free_array function should I free every struct pair in the cycle or free(array) is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Joachim gave the right answer, but the reason the original "sizeof_array()" is incorrect is because "struct array" contains an array of "struct pair" not "uint32_t".  And the struct is twice as big as "sizeof(uint32_t)".

Besides, though unlikely, it's possible that a compiler on some platform could add extra space for alignment in "struct pair".