# c++ Memory crashed

Tags: c++, memory

I have a c++ program running on ubuntu 13.10.
I am facing an error `free(): invalid next size (fast)` randomly.
After a search, [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/c-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast), I found that this error is related to memory allocation/deletion.

Then I use eclipse to debug and I target the location. I found at least two hints about this bug.

1. This error occurs when releasing a data structure like this - std::vector< std::vector< double> >
2. When I compile the program with optimize, error comes out. When I compile it without optimize, no error comes out.

All dynamic memory allocation I done is through stl, such as push_back, resize, etc.
Anyone knows how to fix this bug?

---

Thread [1] 4932 [core: 2] (Suspended : Signal : SIGABRT:Aborted)
    __GI_raise() at raise.c:56 0x7ffff752ef77
    __GI_abort() at abort.c:90 0x7ffff75325e8
    __libc_message() at libc_fatal.c:199 0x7ffff756c4fb 
    malloc_printerr() at malloc.c:4,923 0x7ffff7578996
    _int_free() at malloc.c:3,779 0x7ffff7578996
    deallocate() at new_allocator.h:110 0x416805
    _M_deallocate() at stl_vector.h:174 0x416805
    ~_Vector_base() at stl_vector.h:160 0x416805
    ~vector() at stl_vector.h:416 0x416805
    _Destroy >() at stl_construct.h:93 0x416805 
    __destroy*>() at stl_construct.h:103 0x416805
    _Destroy*>() at stl_construct.h:126 0x416805
    _Destroy*, std::vector >() at stl_construct.h:151 0x416805
    std::vector >, std::allocator > > >::~vector() at stl_vector.h:415 0x416805
    TokenPassBasedDTW() at my_class.cpp:2,203 0x40b237
    InitialVec_Token() at my_class.cpp:2,292 0x41318d
    RUNMANAGER::TokenPassDecoder() at my_class.cpp:2,485 0x413993
    main() at main.cpp:77 0x402774

@dasblinkenlight , is this is the profile?

---

Overview of the program:

```
std::vector< std::vector< double > > Matrix_A(10);
for(size_t i = 0; i < Matrix_A.size(); ++i){
    Matrix_A[i].resize(20);
}
for(size_t i = 0; i < Matrix_A.size(); ++i){
    for(size_t j = 0; j < Matrix_A[i].size(); ++j){
        /*
         * Here I read Matrix_A 
        */

        Matrix_A[i][j] = Val;
    }
}
std::vector< double > Temp_Vector;
Temp_Vector = Matrix_A.back();
double Minimum_Value = *std::min_element(Temp_Vector.begin(), Temp_Vector.end());
Matrix_A.clear();
```

Error occurs when I do Matrix_A.clear();

Comment: You need to memory profile your program. Without this, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be so much easier to find what's wrong.

Comment: Use ApplicationVerifier on Windows, or Valgrind on Linux

Comment: @sflee - Using a `vector` does not insulate you from using an invalid index (if you're accessing the vector using `operator []`).  So you are not safe if you use `vector` incorrectly.

Comment: Frequently, the problem is deallocating something correctly---more than once.

Comment: If your problem is from *"invalid index"*, as PaulMcKenzie said, Using `std::vector::at` instead `operator []` will help you. It throws `std::out_of_range` if index is invalid.

Comment: sflee, you can try `valgrind` memory error detector to quickly find the error. And `free(): invalid next size (fast)` usually means that you did write something outside of allocated memory.

Comment: thx @ikh I have tried std::vector::at and found no index is invalid, but error still exit

Answer (score 0):

The reason why free is crashing is because you are corrupting the heap by writing beyond the boundary of allocated memory. I think the line

```
for(size_t j = 0; k < Matrix_A[i].size(); ++j){
```

should read

```
for(size_t j = 0; j < Matrix_A[i].size(); ++j){
```

Not sure what the value of `k` is