# C: free() invalid next size (fast) error.(CodeBlocks, GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, matrix, free

I have the task to read in a matrix with size m*n from a file, and then multiply it with a vector with length n read from an other file(the files only contains tabulators, and "enters"(I don't know the english name of line endings).(it gets the filenames from command line arguments)

I've written a code in C, and it does the multiplication, but at the end of the run, I get an error "C: free() invalid next size (fast) error" if I compile in debug, and get a segmentation fault if I compile in release. I'm not very familiar with debugging so I don't know how to find this error. It would be very helpful if you could help me out. I've read many of the other questions about this error, but I didn't find a working solution for me.

(I can use only double* and not double** even for the matrix structures, because in further tasks I have to use LAPACK, and it prefers this format.)

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct matrix{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double* matrix;
}Mat;

Mat Read(char* f){
    Mat mat;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 1;
    int m = 1;
    char tmp;

    mat.matrix = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    FILE* file = fopen(f, "r");
    while(fscanf(file,"%lf",&mat.matrix[i]) >=1){
        i++;
        if(i == n){
            n *= 2;
            mat.matrix = (double*)realloc(mat.matrix, n * sizeof(double));
        }
        tmp = fgetc(file);
        if(tmp != '\n' && tmp != EOF){
                m++;
        }else{
            mat.cols = m;
            m = 1;
        }
    }

    mat.rows = i/mat.cols;
    fclose(file);
    return mat;
}

Mat Multipmatvec(Mat mat, Mat vec){
    int i, j;
    Mat ans;
    ans.matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * vec.cols);

    for(i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++){
        ans.matrix[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++){
            ans.matrix[i] += mat.matrix[i*mat.cols+j] * vec.matrix[j];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

void print(Mat mat){
    int i,j;
    if(mat.cols==1){
        for(i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++){
            printf("%lf\n", mat.matrix[i]);
        }
    }else if(mat.rows == 1){
        for(i = 0; i < mat.cols; i++){
            printf("%lf\n", mat.matrix[i]);
        }
    }else{
        for(i = 0; i < mat.rows*mat.cols; i++){
            if(i%mat.cols==0 && i!=0){
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("%lf\t", mat.matrix[i]);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Mat vec;
    Mat ans;
    Mat mat;

    vec = Read(argv[2]);
    mat = Read(argv[1]);

    if (mat.cols % vec.cols != 0){
        printf("Matrix Size Error.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Mat: \n");
    print(mat);
    printf("\nVec: \n");
    print(vec);


    ans.matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double*)*vec.cols);
    ans = Multipmatvec(mat, vec);
    ans.cols = mat.rows;
    ans.rows = 1;


    printf("\nResult:\n");
    print(ans);


    free(vec.matrix);
    free(ans.matrix);
    free(mat.matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might like to read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ on how to learn to debug sich issues yourself.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/4729416/943752

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Answer (score 0):

I was overindexing the ans.matrix structure element. The ans.cols value was 1, and the cycle was running to mat.rows which is at least 1, but usually more.

The corrected version is this(I still get segmentation fault if I compile it in release mode with codeblocks, but there isn't any problem if I compile it with gcc from terminal.):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct matrix{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double* matrix;
}Mat;

Mat Read(char* f){
    Mat mat;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 1;
    int m = 1;
    char tmp;

    mat.matrix = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    FILE* file = fopen(f, "r");
    while(fscanf(file,"%lf",&mat.matrix[i]) >=1){
        i++;
        if(i == n){
            n *= 2;
            mat.matrix = (double*)realloc(mat.matrix, n * sizeof(double));
        }
        tmp = fgetc(file);
        if(tmp != '\n' && tmp != EOF){
                m++;
        }else{
            mat.cols = m;
            m = 1;
        }
    }
    mat.rows = i/mat.cols;
    fclose(file);
    return mat;
}

Mat Multipmatvec(Mat mat, Mat vec){
    int i, j;
    Mat ans;
    ans.matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * mat.rows);
    for(i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++){
        ans.matrix[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++){
            ans.matrix[i] += mat.matrix[i*mat.cols+j] * vec.matrix[j];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

void print(Mat mat){
    int i;
    if(mat.cols==1){
        for(i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++){
            printf("%lf\n", mat.matrix[i]);
        }
    }else if(mat.rows == 1){
        for(i = 0; i < mat.cols; i++){
            printf("%lf\n", mat.matrix[i]);
        }
    }else{
        for(i = 0; i < mat.rows*mat.cols; i++){
            if(i%mat.cols==0 && i!=0){
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("%lf\t", mat.matrix[i]);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Mat vec;
    Mat ans;
    Mat mat;

    vec = Read(argv[2]);
    mat = Read(argv[1]);

    if (mat.cols % vec.cols != 0){
        printf("Matrix Size Error.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Mat: \n");
    print(mat);
    printf("\nVec: \n");
    print(vec);

    ans.matrix = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double*)*vec.cols);
    ans = Multipmatvec(mat, vec);
    ans.cols = mat.rows;
    ans.rows = 1;


    printf("\nResult:\n");
    print(ans);

    free(vec.matrix);
    free(ans.matrix);
    free(mat.matrix);

    return 0;
}
```