# How can I locate error: *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09767150 ***

Tags: c++, runtime-error

My main.cpp and grid.h compile successfully.  The problem occurs when I use the function fill after resizing the grid.  This produces an error after running the program:

> *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0871d150 ***

main.cpp

```
#include "grid.h"
#include <cstdlib>

#if 1
    #define log(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;
#else
    #define log(x) 
#endif  

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_CSTDLIB
    #define clear system("clear");
    #define reset system("reset");
#else
    #define clear
    #define reset
#endif

std::pair<const int, const int> LARGE  = std::make_pair(8,8);
std::pair<const int, const int> MEDIUM = std::make_pair(6,6);
std::pair<const int, const int> SMALL  = std::make_pair(4,4); 


int main(){
    clear
    grid<char> a(LARGE,'#');
    grid<int>  b(4,5,   9 );
    a.resize(4,8);
    b.resize(MEDIUM);
    b.fill(8);
    log(a);
    log(b);
    return 0;
}
```

grid.h

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename type>
class grid{
    public://Functions
        grid(std::pair<const type, const type> dimension, type filler = 0) : rows(dimension.first), cols(dimension.second){
                matrix.assign(rows, std::vector<type>(cols, filler));
        };
        grid(const int _rows, const int _cols, type filler = 0) : rows(_rows), cols(_cols){
                matrix.assign(rows, std::vector<type>(cols, filler));
        };
        void resize(std::pair<const type, const type> dimension){
            rows = dimension.first, cols = dimension.second;
            matrix.resize(rows, std::vector<type>(cols));
        };
        void resize(const int _rows, const int _cols){
            rows = _rows, cols = _cols;
            matrix.resize(rows, std::vector<type>(cols));
        };
        void fill(type filler){
            for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){
                    matrix[r][c] = filler;
                }
            }
        };
    public://Operators
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, grid& g){
            for(int r = 0; r < g.rows; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < g.cols; c++){
                    out << g.matrix[r][c];
                }out << std::endl;
            }return out;
        };
        //Variables
        std::vector<std::vector<type>> matrix;
        int  rows;
        int  cols;
};

#endif//GRID_H
```

Console Output

```
dylan@Aspire-one:~$ ./a.out
########
########
########
########

888888
888888
888888
888888
888888
888888

*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09767150 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
dylan@Aspire-one:~$
```

Comment: You can use a memory debugging tool like valgrind to see imbalanced `free()` calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code? For one, that `########` shouldn't be there (you only have one `log`!), plus I can't reproduce the crash.

Comment: Oh, and I can't see any bug.

Comment: I changed the code.  This edited version should be what I actually have.  I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resize method is incorrect.  If you already have N rows and resize to X rows, any existing rows don't change to the new column size.  When you then use them you have a failure.

Comment: Could you tell me how to fix this then?

Comment: Should I use assign instead?

Comment: If you don't care about performance or the old contents of the matrix, you could simply clear the vector first.  Then the resize will do what you want.  Otherwise, you should resize the outer vector, then loop through and resize the columns one at a time

Comment: Clearing the 2d vector works, but the other method did not:              `void resize(const int _rows, const int _cols){
            rows = _rows, cols = _cols;
            matrix.resize(rows);
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
             matrix[i].resize(cols);
            }
        };`

Comment: I was wrong.  Both methods do work.  I forgot to change both resize functions.

Answer (score 1):

> `Error in './a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0871d150`

This error *always* means that your program corrupted its heap (such as by writing past the end of a heap-allocated buffer).

The *standard* way to find this problem is run your program under Valgrind, which will point you straight at the problem.

Address sanitizer (`gcc -fsanitize=address -g ...`) is another standard tool for finding this.

Comment: I am able to run Address sanitizer.  Can you teach me what to look for?

Comment: This is a comment at best. Nothing in this "answer" identifies the problem.