# C++: Error while deallocating memory -invalid next size

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am trying to delete an array which is passed to a function. However I "sometimes" get **glibc** error: **free(): invalid next size (fast)**

```
int * enlarge(int* arr, int add, int oldsize){
    int *resize= new int[add + oldsize];
    for(int i = 0; i < add +oldsize; i++){
        if(i<oldsize)
            resize[i] = arr[i];
        else
            resize[i] = 0;
    }
    delete [] arr;
    return resize;
}
```

and I call it in this way:

```
p = new int[K];

p = enlarge(p,1,K);
```

I would really appreciate if anyone helps me deleting "arr".

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++!

Comment: I call this code the "new and delete dance".  You have two separate pointers to allocated memory, and you're dancing back and forth between who has what valid pointer.  That is bound to fail at some point.  And if this is supposed to "enlarge the array", I would expect that you use one single pointer to always represent the data pointed to, not two.   Why not just use `std::vector<int>` and use the `resize()` method instead of this?

Comment: Maybe you overstepped an array somewhere else and messed up the heap?

Comment: How is `p` initialized before the call to `enlarge`? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So why are you calling `new` with an `int` type if `p` points to a `double`?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. I have overloaded versions of this function for int and double.

Comment: @BN  So if another type comes along, like `char`, are you going to write another overload?  If you're writing C++, this is not the way to do this.

Comment: @BN Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/qKN5hQ  I suspect your program is much larger and you're utilizing the `enlarge` function in ways that would cause issues.  If that's the case, scrapping this and using `std::vector<int>` sounds like a better idea, as an attempt to fix your larger program would make the code even harder to maintain.

Comment: @BN What if `oldsize` and the real size you allocated are out of synch when you call the `enlarge` function?  I bet that's what's happening.  You pass a raw pointer to `enlarge` and an `oldsize` parameter, and there is no way you will know if `oldsize` is the actual number of elements.  If `oldsize` being passed is larger than the number of real elements, you have a read access error.  This is why you should seriously consider using `std::vector<int>`, as a vector knows its size, and you don't have to write code trying to keep things in synch.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Sorry where is the OP "dancing back and forth" between anything? The function looks pretty straightforward to me (and the problem is likely in the calling scope).

Comment: If the array were created and destroyed within the scope of the `enlarge` function, similar to `bool enlarge(int **p, 1, K);` that would be one thing.   But the way that function is coded encourages or doesn't discourage calls like this: `p = enlarge(q, 1, K);`, where you are going back and forth between p being allocated and q deallocated.  In any event, I still have my bet that in the larger program, the last parameter value is not matching up with the actual number of elements that were allocated if indeed *all* of the calls are of the form `p = enlarge(p, x, y);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Actually I couldn't find any problem with parameters passing and I think they are always in correct domain. However, I decided to change the data structure to vector; yes it is a huge code and it is not mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)