# *** Error in `./recover': free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c

These code is not working!
It have to read 512-byte blocks until ending of file!

- valgrind said that all ok!
- allocated data are freeing at the end

*** Error in `./recover': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x09e89170 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define B_SIZE 512 

char* getTitle (int c);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // TODO

    long size;
    uint32_t *data;

    // open file

    FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open/create file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);


    if (!(data = malloc(512))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(true) // until end
    {
        // read 512 block
        if (ftell(file) >= size-2048)
        {
            printf("STOP\n");
            break;
        }

        fread(data, B_SIZE, 128, file);

        printf("%ld, (%li)\n", ftell(file), size);

    }

    // close all files
    free(data);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read `B_SIZE * 128`(512 * 128 = 64k) bytes into a buffer of only 512 bytes. That will write out of bounds of the allocated memory and lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to read only 512 bytes at a time, then do e.g.

```
fread(data, 1, B_SIZE, file);
```