# free(): invalid next size (fast) when realeasing or allocating memory?

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

I keep getting this error free(): invalid next size (fast), when allocating or releasing memory I think. I'm currently using emacs and I'm not familiar with its debugger at all, any help is greatly appreciated.

here are my constructor, destructor, nont default const and assignment operator that im using

```
T *data;

`//default constructor                                                                    
template <class T> deque <T> :: deque()
{
   numCapacity = 0;
   data = NULL;
}`

//non default constructor                                                                            
template <class T> deque <T> :: deque(int capacity) throw (const char *)
{
   if (capacity == 0)
   {
      numCapacity = 0;
      data = NULL;;
      return;
   }
   try
   {
      data = new T[capacity];
   }
   catch(std::bad_alloc)
   {
      throw "ERROR: Unable to allocate a new buffer for deque";
   }
   numCapacity = capacity;
}
    //copy                                                                                               
template <class T> deque <T> :: deque(const deque<T> & rhs) throw (const char *)
{
   if (rhs.numCapacity == 0)
   {
      numCapacity = 0;
      data = NULL;
      return;
   }
   try
   {
      data = new T[rhs.numCapacity];
   }
   catch (std::bad_alloc)
   {
      throw "ERROR: unable to allocate buffer";
   }
   numCapacity = rhs.numCapacity;
   for (int i = 0; i < numCapacity; i++)
      data[i] = rhs.data[i];
}

//destructor
~deque()
{
     delete [] data;
}
```

//assignment operator

```
//assignment operator                                                                                            
template <class T> deque<T> & deque<T> :: operator = (const deque<T> & rhs) throw (const char *)
{
   T *temp;
   int newSize = 0;

   if (rhs.numCapacity == numCapacity)
   {
      newSize = rhs.numCapacity + 1;
   }
   else if (rhs.numCapacity > numCapacity)
   {
      newSize = rhs.numCapacity;
   }
   else
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
          temp[i] = rhs.data[i];
       data = temp;
       numCapacity = newSize;
       return *this;
   }
 try
      {
         temp = new T[newSize];
      }
      catch(std::bad_alloc)
      {
         throw "ERROR: Unable to allocate a new buffer for deque";
      }

   for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
      temp[i] = rhs.data[i];
   data = temp;
   numCapacity = newSize;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Something somewhere has corrupted the internals of the memory manager. One likely culprit is the lack of assignment operator.

Comment: @molbdnilo i have added my assignment operator

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `temp[i] = rhs.data[i];` in `else` block deferences uninitialized pointer `temp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)