# free(): invalid next size (fast) after several calls

Tags: c++, free, dynamic-allocation

I am entirely unsure how this function can possibly have a bug with memory allocation.

```
template <typename T, typename U> // x -> ax+b
void transform_coords(double a, double b, int n, const T* oldc, U* newc) {
  int i, j, q0, q;
  if (n<2) return;

  int *p = new int[n]; // Pascal's triangle
  p[0] = 1;
  for (i=1; i<n; ++i) p[i] = 0;
  for (i=0; i<n; ++i) newc[i] = 0;

  for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      if (p[i]==0) break;
      double m = p[i];
      if (i!=j) m *= std::pow(a,j-i);
      if (i!=0) m *= std::pow(b,i);
      newc[i] += m * oldc[j];
    }
    for (i=1, q=1; q; ++i) {
      q0 = p[i];
      p[i] += q;
      q = q0;
    }
  }

  delete[] p;
}
```

On the **third** call I get

```
*** glibc detected *** ./bin/bin_var: free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

If I comment out `delete[] p;` it runs fine through all the calls.

As far as I see, concerning memory allocation, this function is equivalent to

```
void transform_coords(int n) {
  if (n<2) return;
  int *p = new int[n];
  delete[] p;
}
```

Comment: Post a complete program, a [MCVE], all in one piece, ready to cut and paste.

Comment: The most likely problem is that you're writing past the bounds of one of those arrays.

Comment: The C++ way of doing this is to use `std::vector<int> p(n)`. It will clean-up after itself, no need to worry about deleting it.

Comment: What he said. Don't use `new` and `delete` or  raw pointers with ownership obligations. Use standard containers.

Comment: @TomdeGeus yup, I know. It doesn't invalidate the question, though ;) `new[]` and `detele[]` are still in the standard. If someone asks why their car isn't working, you don't expect a mechanic to tell them to get a better car.

Comment: @S.M. See that `if (n<2) return;` at the top of the function?

Comment: @TomdeGeus That said, I always use `std::vector`. This is just an oddball function.

Comment: If you comment out all the loops between `new` and `delete` do you still get the error?

Comment: *If I comment out delete[] p; it runs fine through all the calls.* -- And leaks like crazy.  Why not print out the value of `i` in the last loop, so as to check if it goes out-of-bounds?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree. That was just one of the things I tried to diagnose the problem. I wasn't going to leave it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in one of your loops. As said [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast) on *Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):*

> You may be overflowing a buffer or otherwise writing to memory to which you shouldn't be writing, causing heap corruption.

My best guess is this loop:

```
for (i=1, q=1; q; ++i) {
  q0 = p[i];
  p[i] += q;
  q = q0;
}
```

if `p` array is not `0` terminated, this will overwrite memory in the heap.

That being said, if you use `std::vector` instead of a manually allocated array, your code would be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks, @Gill. That's it. This loop is not meant to run on the very last iteration of the `j`-loop. I overlooked that. Since the error said `free`, I thought it was about memory deallocation, not about writing past the array end.

Comment: I don't see how `std::vector` would fix this. `std::vector::operator[]` does not perform bounds checking, so you'd be still writing past end of allocated array, corrupting memory.